# Are the rings $\mathbb Z^2$ and $G$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. We endow $R \times R$ with pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication. Then it's easy to verify that $R \times R$ is a ring under these operations. Let $G = \{m+ni\mid (m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2\}$ with $i^2 = -1$ be the set of Gaussian integers. We endow $G$ with addition and multiplication of complex numbers. Then $G$ is a ring under these operations.

Clearly, the map $G \to \mathbb Z^2, m+ni \mapsto (m,n)$ is a bijection, but not a ring homomorphism (because it does not preserves multiplicative structure).

As such, I would like to ask if the ring $\mathbb Z^2$ and $G$ are isomorphic.

Thank you so much for your clarification!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has nontrivial zero divisors, namely $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$, so it doesn't embed into any field, and so can't be isomorphic to any ring which does. In other words it's not an integral domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've just realized that your answers (and even comments) are very rich of information. Many thanks for you.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not isomorphic since $x^2=-1$ does not have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

If there exists an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow G$, $f(1,1)=1$. Let $(m,n)$ such that $f(m,n)=i$, $f((m,n)^2)=f(m^2,n^2)=-1=f(-1,-1)$. Implies that
$(-1,-1)=(m^2,n^2)$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

They are not isomorphic since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is not.